# Dual Monitors for Windows 8

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8, resolution

I have one monitor and a projector connecting to my computer, while the screen keep flashing after every 10 seconds, it seems the resolution keeps changing.

The project is the a dual display for the monitor. They displays the same content.

My current resolution is 1024*768, while after 10 seconds around, the resolution goes to something big, then after a few seconds, it goes back to 1024*768.

I wonder if this is a problem about the resolution, or it's about the compatible of screen display?

Comment: Is it the projector or monitor that is changing resolution every 10 seconds?

Comment: They both do change every 10 seconds.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with drivers.

Comment: Drivers? How to fix that? Upgrade the driver?

Comment: Start by finding your graphics card manufacturer's website, and finding the latest drivers for your card there.

Comment: I'll go and get a try on that.

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest graphics driver.
I have heard this problem occurring in one the intel boards earlier.
Goto the intel site (or whichever graphics card you have) and look for your card's specific graphics drivers.

Also get a BIOS update for your motherboard ( another driver update)

One more thing you should check is whether there are any duplicate drivers in the device manager.